# Reading the Android Source code

Tags: android, git, curl, repo

I am currently compiling ROM from the android source and it works fine 
But now I have decided to read about all the packages that are used I.e.
Git , make , gnu , repo , curl, libdev ..

But I also want to read the android core source code .
Can anyone point out from where should I start ?
Also what languages do I need to know?
Currently I am familiar with C , C++ , Java 
Also I have made android apps of my own , so I am familiar with android environment
And also mark up languages like XML HTML JavaScript

I suppose if I need to read kernel source code I need to learn assembly language?
Though I would keep the kernel aside for now .

Answer (score 1):

The main code of Android are written by java and c&c++. The SDK are java code and bind to native code via JNI.

So, the SDK code should be a good start since you already familiar with those API. Then, you can dig into it and reach the native layer.

Comment: So I should read source code of SDK and then see how the code for APIs are written . what do u mean by "reach the native later " ?

Comment: The SDK is JAVA code but some of them are depend on native code( c/c++ code ). So when you reading the SDK code, you will found some implementation are c/c++. The JAVA layer invoke those native functions by JNI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to buy yourself a dev-kit like RIoT board or Wandboard, and install Android on it. You can then compile Android yourself, step through it etc. That will give you ideas on what part of the platform you should read. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with Eclipse Android SDK https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
You have a fully overview on every android project like this, C++ is enough, XML are located in /res/layout for U.I.!
[a project libs overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM0Om.png)

Comment: I know how to develop apps ..I was asking about android platform source code n not android application source code

Comment: Do you mean you want to work with Android Runtime?
Sorry I can't help, find out what you need on Android Achitecture.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/t44JO.jpg